# printing selected rows from a file using awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a text file with data in the following format.

```
1 0 0
2 512 6
3 992 12
4 1536 18
5 2016 24
6 2560 29
7 3040 35
8 3552 41
9 4064 47
10 4576 53
11 5088 59
12 5600 65
13 6080 71
14 6592 77
15 7104 83
```

I want to print all the lines where $1 > 1000.

```
awk 'BEGIN {$1 > 1000} {print "  " $1 "  "$2 "  "$3}' graph_data_tmp.txt
```

This doesn't seem to give the output that I am expecting.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
awk '$1>1000 {print $0}' graph_data_tmp.txt
```

`print $0` will print all the content of the line

If you want to print the content of the line after the 1000th line/ROW, then you could do the same by replacing `$1` with `NR`. NR represents the number of rows.

```
awk 'NR>1000 {print $0}' graph_data_tmp.txt
```

Comment: `NR` is for the line number. `$1` is the first column. At least in your example, you don't have 1000 lines. You have 1000 lines, then replacing, `$1` with `NR > 1000` will print line contents beyond 1000 lines

Comment: I do have more that 1000 lines in the original file.:) thanks BEGIN was causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is:

```
awk '$1>1000' file
```